# Quickly increment selected numbers in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm working on a plain text configuration file that has a configuration key format of

> `<type name>_<#>_<Subcomponent name>=<value>`

To be a little more clear, the configuration file refers to a group of computers, so the type name could be `COMPUTER`, and subcomponent name could be `IP` or `PORT`, for instance.  So I have a block of keys for computer 1 and its subcomponents, a block for computer 2, etc throughout the file.

Adding a single new block of keys is relatively easy, but adding multiple blocks becomes a tedious column selecting exercise.  Since the type name is the same length throughout the file, I want to be able to do a column select through all the numbers that need changing, and quickly increment them.  I don't see anything in TextFX that will do this, which would be the obvious option.  Is there another way to do this quickly and easily?

As a side note, I know I could write a Perl script to do this, but it'd be a little to indiscriminate as I don't want to increment all numbers, just a group of them.

Answer (score 3):

You may have to do it in batches (if your number column isn't zero padded to a constant width) but you can use column-selection (just tested working as of notepad++ 5.9.3) to select just the numbers, then use Edit->Column Editor (Alt-C) to set your start and end numbers.

This may not be much help either, if your numbers are neither zero-padded nor ordered, but hopefully it will be some help.

Comment: Ooh, so close.  The number needs to be repeated through the various sub-components.  I'll edit the question to be a little clearer about what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you paste to excel a text in witch line contains tabs separators, you'll get a useful sheet; so:

- replace space with TAB chars using extended search (replace "_" and "=" with "\t")
- copy and paste to excel, renumber the column content
- copy and paste back to notepad++
- replace tab with "_" and restore the "=" column typing into a rectangular selection (ALT+mouse selection) 1 char width.

Comment: This probably does the trick, but it's just as much work as @GeminiDomino answer.  The point of the question is to do one or two clicks after the column select.  See [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/183882/) for why your solution isn't so nice.

Answer (score 0):

Lately i've used OpenOffice Calc (works in any spreadsheet actually - from Excel to Google Docs) to do this for me in a "looks dumb, but it works" way.

1. In cells A1 and A2 added some numbers (1,2).
2. In cell B1 created a "formula" like:

   ```
   ="Some filler part "&$A1&" here;"
   ```
3. Drag-filled A1:A2 down to A31 to fill it as source column.
4. Drag-filled B1 to B31 to fill it as output data.

   The result was 31 rows with strings like:

   > Some filler part 1 here;
   >   Some filler part 2 here;
   >   Some filler part 3 here;
   >   ...
   >   Some filler part 31 here;
5. Selected column B and copy-pasted it to Notepad++.

I prefer doing it this way, just because Excel/Calc doesn't need any external macros or anything to accomplish tasks of this kind.

Comment: Either I don't understand your answer, or you don't understand my question.  I have the feeling that it's the latter.