# Adding 1 Incrementally in Search & Replace in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a file that I want to extract data out of.  I normally use web scraping to get the info I need, except in this case the information isnt readily "visible" for scraping needs.  Reason being -- the data I need is called inside of a parent class  Anyways, thats beside the point....

Each class is uniquely identified by a date. However the information I want is listed right below this as a particular class ( but they are always called the same thing ).

What I would like to do is use a macro to loop thru the file and each time it comes across this class ( we'll call it a string "GET_THIS" ), I'd like to call it "GET_THIS"+1 . Ex:
The first instance would be GET_THIS1
The second instance would be GET_THIS2
The third instance would be GET_THIS3
....

Until end of file.

Any ideas or input would be awesome!

Comment: Just to clarify, you are looking to replace all instances of the string "GET_THIS" with "GET_THIS"+ a number that increments as it finds/replaces instances of "GET_THIS"?

Comment: Perhaps check out: [Quickly increment selected numbers in Notepad++](http://superuser.com/questions/339948/quickly-increment-selected-numbers-in-notepad) and/or [Find/Replace but Increment Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105621/find-replace-but-increment-value)